# Jekyll: Highlighting code snippets using markdown syntax

Tags: markdown, jekyll, github-flavored-markdown

The [Jekyll docs](http://jekyllrb.com/docs/posts/) state that code highlighting is done using Liquid tags as follows:

```
{% highlight ruby %}
def show
  @widget = Widget(params[:id])
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html # show.html.erb
    format.json { render json: @widget }
  end
end
{% endhighlight %}
```

However, I would rather like to use Markdown syntax:

````
```ruby
def foo
  puts 'foo'
end
```
````

I tried it myself the following way:

````
``` ini
; Disables the splash screen, if it has been compiled into the launcher.
RunLocally=true
```
````

However, the result does not look the way it should.

[image]

Comment: I am not entirely sure whether it was a caching issue on Github or a missing config setting but I added `markdown: redcarpet` to `_config.yml` and now code samples are rendered using the markdown syntax.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I had to add the following to my _config.yml to get my GitHub Pages syntax highlighting to work:

```
markdown: redcarpet
extensions: [fenced_code_blocks]
```

I don't know why `fenced_code_blocks` is required for GitHub Pages, since it's supposed to be enabled by default in Jekyll.

Comment: Does this hold for Jekyll 3?